# nModified:0 and write performance

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to improve update performance of my application that use mongodb. 
Trying different ways of performing an update using the mongo shell I notice something that I don't manage to explain.
In some conditions I have "nModified" : 1 even if I feed the same document.
Following some examples that I made:

```
> var doc = {k:10, c:1,c:2}
> var key = {k:10}
> db.foo.update(key,doc, {upsert:1})  
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 1, "nModified" : 0 })
> db.foo.update(key,doc, {upsert:1}) // I was expecting nModified:0 
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

but if I use $set mongo is able to see that the document stored is the same and then nModified is set to 0:

```
> db.foo.update(key,{$set:doc}, {upsert:1})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Same if I try to replace the document specifying also the _id in the first position

```
> doc = db.foo.findOne(key)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ded9c0595d0be1b0eb734c"), "k" : 10, "c" : 2 }
> db.foo.update(key,{$set:doc}, {upsert:1})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
> db.foo.update(key,doc, {upsert:1})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

But not if I place the _id in the end of the document:

```
> var doc = {k:10, c:1,c:2}
> doc._id = db.foo.findOne(key)._id
> doc
{ "k" : 10, "c" : 2, "_id" : ObjectId("55ded9c0595d0be1b0eb734c") }
> db.foo.update(key,doc, {upsert:1})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.foo.update(key,doc, {upsert:1})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Now I am wondering if this can impact performance in the way that when we have nModified:0 write performance are speed up.

I hope my examples are clear enough

Comment: The reason is because the "keys" of the object can possibly be "reordered" on write from how you sent them. This makes it a different object. Operators like `$addToSet` work in the same way, where a different key order is considered a "unique" object. It also gives good reason why you use `$set` as this will not be the case if the content is already the same as what is there.

Comment: I believe after looking at the question more this comes down to the equality match between documents within MongoDB itself. The documents are not actually equal when not using $set as such they are written

Comment: @BlakesSeven  do you have a reference for that?